# Assigning keyboard key command "cmd+c" function to "cmd+c+[keyboard number]" to store multiple copies

Tags: macos, stored-procedures, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste

I'm running on OSX. Is there a way to do this? While programming I'd like to store a few lines of code with keyboard shortcuts to copy a few different copies of different lines without having to get rid what's stored in my cmd+c. Where I could save different copies of different items <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, and <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> etc. and paste for them as well.

I'm assuming this is going to have to be done (if it can be done) is going to be done on the OS level via terminal commands and I'm not as good as others with terminal commands and OS programming so I didn't know if there was anything like this out there and if it's not I would like to do it myself so any help pointers or suggestions would be great.

Comment: You can _sort of_ achieve this with [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) and it's snippet function.